# Difference between forward and sendRedirect

Tags: java, jsp

I have come across these two statements on an interview question on the web:

```
 1.forward causes object stored in request as attributes to be lost;
 2.sendRedirect causes object stored in request as attributes to be lost;
```

I am now confident that the first statement is wrong since using request is definitely how forward works to pass values, but I am confused about the sendRedirect one, is it correct in this sense? Could experts help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `forward` which happens on the server-side, `sendRedirect` causes the browser to initiate a new request to the redirect location, which means the second statement is true.