# how to send variables with sendRedirect()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

by using the method `forward()` I can "send" variables  using `request.setAttribute()`.

What if i should use `sendRedirect()` instead?? How can i "send" a variable to the destination page?

I don't like to do something like this: `sendRedirect("page?varName=varValues")`, i don't like to see variables names and values  written on the browser.

Is there a way to send variables in a hidden way when using `sendRedirect()`?

Thank you

Comment: you might want to take time to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001185/pass-hidden-parameters-using-response-sendredirect)

Answer (score 1):

In theory, we cannot send the POST request by using the sendRedirect().

But there is a possible solution if you insiste on passing the hidden parameters by sendRedirect(). And you can set those parameters in the object session.

For example :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

session.setAttribute("parameter", "parameter");

response.sendRedirect("/page");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Attribute on the `session` and not the `request` so you can access it from the redirected page. But there is multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The possible way is is to set in the session like something below,

```
session.setAttribute("varName", "value");
response.sendRedirect("/resultPage");
```

This will redirect to the result page and you can get the value from session as,

```
session.getAttribute("varName");
```

the `session` object will be available through out the application till you invalidate it manually.

> *The reason why `RequestDispatcher forward()` method holds the request object is that it forwards the same request and `sendRedirect()`
>   doesnt do that because it creates new request each time*

[Learn More ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551876/difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect)